# Create a "forCount" control structure in Swift

Tags: swift, macros, preprocessor, language-features

In many projects this control structure is ideal for readability:

```
forCount( 40 )
 {
 // this block is run 40 times
 }
```

You can do [exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844280/294884)  in objective-C.

Given that Swift has a **very different approach to macros** than objective-c,

is there a way to create such a `forCount(40)` control structure in Swift projects?

---

Some similar concepts in Swift:

```
for _ in 1...40
 { // this block is run 40 times }
```

Using an [ingenious extension to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554255/294884) ...

```
40.times
 { // this block is run 40 times }
```

Comment: See also http://www.drewag.me/posts/7-cool-features-in-swift#extend-structs-and-literals.

Comment: Hi Martin, the "5.times" extension trick is terrific, and I do thank you, but I was really wondering if there was a way to make wordHere(n) work syntactically, as one can easily when there's a preprocessor. As it says in the question.  Not so much looking for the shortest way to do it.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question (sorry for that!), I have re-opened it.

Comment: au contraire, thanks all around!  questions were meant to be closed an opened and closed!

Comment: Adding a “repeat N times” feature to the Swift language is currently discussed on the Swift evolution forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/straightforward-code-repetition/13828.

Comment: @MartinR, fascinating, thanks for that !  Key for every game engineer

Comment: That forum is open to everyone – you are welcome to contribute your arguments!

Comment: I'd be too shy man!  it's all pro users there!   :O

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no preprocessor macros in Swift, but you can define a global *function* taking the iteration count and a closure as arguments:

```
func forCount(count : Int, @noescape block : () -> ()) {
    for _ in 0 ..< count {
        block()
    }
}
```

With the "trailing closure syntax", it *looks* like a built-in
control statement:

```
forCount(40) {
    print("*")
}
```

The `@noescape` attribute allows the compile to make some optimizations
and to refer to instance variables without using `self`, see
[@noescape attribute in Swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427436/noescape-attribute-in-swift-1-2) for more information.

As of **Swift 3,** "noescape" is the default attribute for function
parameters:

```
func forCount(_ count: Int, block: () -> ()) {
    for _ in 0 ..< count {
        block()
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin, it's great to help out a new user like yourself by sending over 100 points :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
let resultArr = (0..<n).map{$0+5}
```

or

```
(0..<n).forEach{print("Here\($0)")}
```

Comment: By far the cleanest, easiest-to-read, most-Swifty syntax -- leverage ```map``` to avoid extensions and / or non-Swifty global functions.